# What GC algorithm should I use in order to prevent high CPU usage?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, cpu

I am running my Java application in 512MB space heap size. I noticed, in case of OOM, CPU usage is too high because multiple GC threads were running. I used GC algorithm Parallel/Throughput GC. Then I increased heap size to 1024MB, but still for some cases we have high CPU usage, resulting in *"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded"*.

I want to reduce CPU high usage. I have gone through [GC algorithms](https://www.baeldung.com/java-choosing-gc-algorithm), but I do not understand which GC algorithm will suit for my use case. OOM is not a problem, I only want to reduce high CPU usage. Could some one help on this?

My Java version is Java 8.

Comment: This is well outside my expertise, but if the GC is using too much cpu... have you considered reducing the number of objects allocated?

Comment: @MooingDuck we are running set of java process via process builder to perform high memory task. we are processing some files in java process. 95 % case its not giving OOM but for some cases invalid file (file size= 2kb) but its giving OOM. in such cases only CPU usage is high. so for that case i want to prevent high CPU usage.

Comment: High memory is totally fine. Using lots of memory is fine. But it sounds like your problem is that the GC is using too much cpu. But the GC CPU directly relates to the *count* of objects freed, relative to free memory. If you allocate and release 50% fewer objects, then CPU usage should drop ~50%.  [Android banned enums for years for exactly this reason](https://medium.com/trade-me/android-then-and-now-intro-intdef-enums-bca22d5cca56)

Comment: Also Android's [ArrayMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/ArrayMap), [LongSparseArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LongSparseArray), [SparseArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray), [SparseLongArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseLongArray), and similar. It's also why Guava was bascially banned on Android until they rewrote it to use far fewer allocations https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Android

Comment: If you'd really prefer to get an `OutOfMemoryError` than high CPU consumption from garbage collection, an extreme option is the [Epsilon](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/epsilon-the-jdks-do-nothing-garbage-collector) experimental garbage collector in Java 11 that doesn't collect garbage at all. You would need to size your heap to allow for all of the allocations needed for the life of the program, but if you're launching a process to process a file and then exit, it might actually work for limited data sizes.

Comment: On the other hand, you would probably get better efficiency from using threads to process files rather than a set of external processes, and using a conventional garbage collector with a larger heap size. And if the high GC activity only occurs for large files, can you check the file size ahead of time and fail fast?

Comment: Fix the running-out-of-memory problem first.  Then the GC will be fine.

Comment: If you consider “high CPU usage” in the sense of “all cores are used” a problem, just don’t use the ParallelGC. The SerialGC will use only one core. But where’s the sense in not using the available CPU resources?

Comment: The _"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded"_ means that Java spent too much time garbage collecting, but hardly freeing any memory. This means your application requires more memory than you've currently allocated. Either increase the amount of memory, or reduce your memory allocation.